# Mongodb find document in collection from field in another collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections: Sharing and Material.

Sharing:

```json
{
 from_id: 2
 to_id: 1
 material_id: material1
}
```

Material:

```json
{
 _id: material1
 organization_id: 2
},
{
 _id: material2
 organization_id: 1
},
{
 _id: material3
 organization_id: 1
},
```

--Edit:
There are three materials, 2 belong to organization_id(1) and 1 belongs to organization_id(2). The organization_id does not match 1 in material1 (and instead belongs to material2), but in the Sharing collection, the to_id does match 1. If the match exists, I'd like to find the Material document _id which is equal to the material_id of Sharing AND find the Material documents where the organization_id is equal to 1.

I'd like to check if a field in Sharing (to_id) has a value that is equal to a field in Material (organization_id) AND check if organization_id is equal to 1. If there is a document that exists from this, do another check to find whether the _id of Material is equal to the material_id of Sharing and return all documents & the total count.

If there is no equal value, I'd like to omit that result and send the object with only organization_id equal to 1 and get the total count of this result.

Right now, I do it in a very inefficient way using .map() to find this. Below is my code:

```js
export const getMaterials = async (req, res) => {
    const sharing = await Sharing.find({to_id: 1});
    let doneLoad;

    try {
        if (sharing && sharing.length>0) {
            const sharingTotal = await Material.find( {$or: [ {organization_id: 1}, {_id: sharing.map((item) => item.material_id)} ] } ).countDocuments();
            const sharingMats = await Material.find( {$or: [ {organization_id: 1}, {_id: sharing.map((item) => item.material_id)} ] } );
            res.status(200).json({data: sharingMats});
            doneLoad= true;
        }
        else if (!doneLoad) {
            const materialTotal = await Material.find({organization_id: 1}).countDocuments();
            const materials = await Material.find({organization_id: 1});
            res.status(200).json({data: materials});
        }
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });       
    }
}
```

I have tried using aggregation to get my desired result but I cannot find any solution that fits my requirements. Any help would be great as I am quite new to using mongodb. Thanks.

Edit (desired result):

```json
Materials: [
{
 _id: material1,
 organization_id: 1
},
{
 _id: material2,
 organization_id: 1
},
{
 _id: material3,
 organization_id: 1
}
]
```

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bRxNMmwAnSN) similar to what you are looking for...?

Comment: Hi ray, it seems quite close actually - thank you very much for the quick reply. I'm looking to find all of the documents in the Materials collection by three conditions really. If the to_id exists from the Sharings collection (equal to organization_id) and the material_id from this match is equal to the _id of the document in the Materials collection, show those results. If there is no match from the Sharings collection, just find the organization_id of Materials equal to 1.

Comment: Your updated dataset has duplicate `_id`, which is not valid document. Nevertheless, see if [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3bp0frA8DpY) helps.

Comment: I've tried to clarify a bit more the requirements in the original answer to explain more about finding both documents from different matches, thank you Ray.

Comment: It seems the `organization_id` in result will always be 1 anyway. Please check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/57al68Ms8Gk) to see if this is what you expected. Basically it is an `$or` condition now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244195/discussion-between-lwnsjdu-and-ray).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sub-pipeline in a `$lookup` to perform the filtering. `$addFields` the count using `$size` later.

```js
db.Sharing.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      to_id: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Material",
      "let": {
        to_id: "$to_id",
        material_id: "$material_id"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            $expr: {
              $or: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$to_id",
                    "$organization_id"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$material_id",
                    "$_id"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$addFields": {
            "organization_id": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "materialLookup"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "materialCount": {
        $size: "$materialLookup"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/57al68Ms8Gk) for your reference.